# PG800 copy functionality throws programming error

Tags: python, postgresql, csv

I have a function that performs a copy to a PSQL database from a CSV file.

Here's the function:

```
def get(self):
        filename = export_user_usermetadata_to_gcs()
        command = """
        INSERT INTO import_temp_table_user_passport_misc
        (profileid, terms_accepted, lastname, firstname, picture_serving_url,
        is_active, is_passport_active, language, created, modified,
        passport_completion_level, email, about_me, uni_code, meta_data)
        VALUES(%s), (%s), (%s), (%s), (%s), (%s), (%s), (%s), (%s), (%s), (%s), (%s), (%s), (%s), (%s)
        """
        location = '/prod-data-migration-csv-exports/{}'.format(filename)
        with gcs.open(location) as data_stream_source:
            reader = csv.reader(data_stream_source)
            slice = itertools.islice(reader, 5000)
            while slice:
                db.executemany(command, slice)
                slice = itertools.islice(reader, 5000)
```

The table `import_temp_table_user_passport_misc` has an extra column called `autoid` which is an incremental integer value.

The error thrown is: `ProgrammingError: (u'ERROR', u'ERROR', u'42601', u'INSERT has more target columns than expressions', u'79', u'analyze.c', u'884', u'transformInsertRow')`. Do I need to specify a column or a value for the autoincrement column?

Here's the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE public.import_temp_table_user_passport_misc
(
    autoid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('import_temp_table_user_passport_misc_autoid_seq'::regclass),
    profileid text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    terms_accepted text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    lastname text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    firstname text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    picture_serving_url text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    is_active text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    is_passport_active text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    language text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    created text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    modified text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    passport_completion_level text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    email text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    about_me text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    uni_code text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    meta_data text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT import_temp_table_user_passport_misc_pkey PRIMARY KEY (autoid)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement has a [values  table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-values.html) with a bunch of single column rows, but from the looks of it you meant a single row such as `VALUES (%s, %s, ..., %s)`:

```
command = """
      INSERT INTO import_temp_table_user_passport_misc
      (profileid, terms_accepted, lastname, firstname, picture_serving_url,
      is_active, is_passport_active, language, created, modified,
      passport_completion_level, email, about_me, uni_code, meta_data)
      VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
      """
```

Comment: This is correct, it fixed my issue, however it's taking forever to run the query (past the 10min mark). Any way you see fit I can optimize the CSV import?

Comment: In case of Postgresql use the [COPY statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html).

Comment: Yes, however the csv is in a URL (google cloud storage).

Comment: Should make no difference as long as you can mangle it to a file like object and pass it as the [stream](http://pythonhosted.org/pg8000/dbapi.html#pg8000.Cursor.execute) argument. Disclaimer: never really used pg8000. So something like `db.execute("COPY import_temp_table_user_passport_misc
        (profileid, terms_accepted, lastname, firstname, picture_serving_url,
        is_active, is_passport_active, language, created, modified,
        passport_completion_level, email, about_me, uni_code, meta_data) FROM STDIN FORMAT CSV", stream=data_stream_source)`.